# send erc 20 tokens with full code example

Tags: web3js, erc-20, sendtransaction

I apologize for posting another question.  Here I'm giving the full example code which is giving me the respond: "txHash undefined" when I try to send erc20. I want to fix this code. If you have even smaller ABI share it.

```
const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
const Web3Utils = require('web3-utils');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/your infura');

var myAddress ='put your address';
var destinationAddres='put the destination address';  
var contractAddress = "put the contracta address";  //  contract code 

privatekeyP='your private key';

const privateKey1=Buffer.from(privatekeyP, 'hex');



var ABI = [{
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "name",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
      "name": "_spender",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "name": "_value",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "name": "approve",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "totalSupply",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
      "name": "_from",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "name": "_to",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "name": "_value",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "name": "transferFrom",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "INITIAL_SUPPLY",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "decimals",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint8"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
      "name": "_spender",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "name": "_subtractedValue",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "name": "decreaseApproval",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [{
      "name": "_owner",
      "type": "address"
  }],
  "name": "balanceOf",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "balance",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [],
  "name": "symbol",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "string"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
      "name": "_to",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "name": "_value",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "name": "transfer",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": false,
  "inputs": [{
      "name": "_spender",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "name": "_addedValue",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "name": "increaseApproval",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "bool"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "constant": true,
  "inputs": [{
      "name": "_owner",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "name": "_spender",
      "type": "address"
  }],
  "name": "allowance",
  "outputs": [{
      "name": "",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "view",
  "type": "function"
}, {
  "inputs": [],
  "payable": false,
  "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
  "type": "constructor"
}, {
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [{
      "indexed": true,
      "name": "owner",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "indexed": true,
      "name": "spender",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "indexed": false,
      "name": "value",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "name": "Approval",
  "type": "event"
}, {
  "anonymous": false,
  "inputs": [{
      "indexed": true,
      "name": "from",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "indexed": true,
      "name": "to",
      "type": "address"
  }, {
      "indexed": false,
      "name": "value",
      "type": "uint256"
  }],
  "name": "Transfer",
  "type": "event"
}]

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress, {
    from: myAddress
});

web3.eth.getTransactionCount(myAddress, (err,txCount)=>{
  // build the transaction


     const txObject = {

      nonce: Web3Utils.toHex(txCount),
      to: contractAddress,
      value: Web3Utils.toHex(0),
      gasLimit: Web3Utils.toHex(91000),
      gasPrice: Web3Utils.toHex(Web3Utils.toWei('10','gwei')),
      data:contract.methods.transfer(destinationAddres,web3.utils.toHex(0)).encodeABI()

  }


      const tx = new Tx(txObject, { chain: 'mainnet'})
    tx.sign(privateKey1);

    const serializedTransaction =tx.serialize();
    const raw ='0x'+ serializedTransaction.toString('hex');



    // Broadcast the transaction
    web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw,(err, txHash)=>{
        console.log('txHash', txHash);
    })


})
```

Comment: `web3 6.9.0`? Current official version is around 1.2.4. There's a 2.x alpha version, but nowhere near 6.

Comment: What do you mean by "it fails" ? What is the error ? Moreover, the latest version of web3 on npm is 1.2.5 (https://www.npmjs.com/package/web3). You can check your version of web3 by using this: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3.html#version

Comment: "Everything I tried" - I'd expect by the least to see `myContract.methods.transfer` somewhere in your code.

Comment: npm web3 -v gives me 6.9.0. I had troubles to install it so I used --force.  I updated my code. When I launch it with data it returns txHash Null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function (tested with web3.js v1.2.1):

```
const ABI = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}];

async function send(web3, contractAddress, destAddress, destAmount, privateKey, gasPrice) {
    const contract    = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);
    const transaction = contract.methods.transfer(destAddress, destAmount);
    const account     = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey).address;

    const options = {
        to      : contractAddress,
        data    : transaction.encodeABI(),
        gas     : await transaction.estimateGas({from: account}),
        gasPrice: gasPrice
    };

    const signed  = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    return receipt;
}
```

---

### Updating the answer according to your updating of the question:

This is wrong:

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress, {from: myAddress});
```

Either you create this object:

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress)
```

And then deploy a new contract by signing and sending this transaction:

```
contract.deploy({data: "0x" + BIN, arguments: [...]})
```

Or you create this object in order to connect to an already deployed contract:

```
var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractAddress);
```

Comment: contractAddress='contract address';
destAddress='destination address';
destAmount='0';
privateKey='aprivatekeygohere';
gasPrice=7;

send(web3, contractAddress, destAddress, destAmount, privateKey, gasPrice); When I try like this it gives me this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when instantiating a contract object.

Comment: Can you give me some example code about how you launch function? Maybe private key needs to start from 0x or gas price should be in hex?

Comment: @Mikheilmisha: First of all, it's an `async` function. So you need to do either one of the following: 1. Resolve the `Promise` object that it returns. 2. `await` for it to complete (must be done from inside another `async` function). 3. Call it at the very end of your script (nothing after that line).

Comment: Second, `gasPrice=7`??? That's extremely low. Perhaps you meant 7 followed by 9 zeros?

Comment: Third - I have no idea which lime of code has thrown the error that you're describing. Please conduct a minimal debug investigation to find that line to begin with.

Comment: Fourth - `contractAddress='contract address'; destAddress='destination address';` - you're joking, right???

Comment: Thanks. I'll make clear web3 install and slowly will try to dig the problem. I'm working with web3 for a while now but I'm kinda still inexperienced since I was using others code and modifying it. Yeah, gasPrice was a mistake, thanks for letting me to know.

Comment: No, not joking with destination address I just removed sample values.

Comment: I just edited my question with the full code with which I have a problem, can you have a look in it and point out a reason? Thank you.

Comment: @Mikheilmisha: I forgot `[]` around the ABI object in my code, so you can start with that. I'll have a look to see if I can "push" some of your details into my solution.

Comment: I don't know how and why, my code is working now. From your code I'll implement await transaction.estimateGas({from: account}) . It's very useful! Thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: Probably I fixed the problem because I increases gas limit. Not really sure.